# Google Sheets Automation

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic, copy

I'm looking to automate data in Google Sheets. Some of my script is working according to plan, but some of it isn't. When I click a button in my sheet it copies Sheet rows/columns to a Master Schedule sheet. This part seems to be working fine.  When I go back in, I want the script to move the data copied to Master Sheet down, leaving space for the new copied data, while leaving history of the previous copy.  Therefore, the script needs to move rows down dynamically.

for instance...

a sheet called Schedule Fill is used to populate data for a specific day.

Data could be
class a - teacher jones, teacher smith
class b - teacher frank, teacher jones
class c - teacher lee, teacher diaz

Once the copy button is clicked this data copies over to Master Schedule in the same rows and columns
class a - teacher jones, teacher smith
class b - teacher frank, teacher jones
class c - teacher lee, teacher diaz

The next day Schedule Fill is refreshed with new data
class a - teacher adams, teacher monroe
class b - teacher lee, teacher castle
class c - teacher jones, teacher frank
Once the copy button is clicked this data copies over to Master Schedule in the same rows and columns and moves the page down x rows...like this...

The Master Schedule now looks like this...
class a - teacher adams, teacher monroe
class b - teacher lee, teacher castle
class c - teacher jones, teacher frank

class a - teacher jones, teacher smith
class b - teacher frank, teacher jones
class c - teacher lee, teacher diaz

My issue is I'm moving rows down statically, so the next time I go in and click copy it will move the last copy down and copy over the data.  I need to keep the last copy at the top, while moving the previous copy down dynamically, but I'm not sure how to do this. and move it down the page....

Here's the script I have so far...  Many Thanks if anyone has any advice.

```
function CopyData() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A1:L13').activate();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Master Schedule'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'Schedule Fill\'!A1:L13').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};

function MoveRowsDown() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A16').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('1:13').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify the moveRowsDown in order not to actually move the data, but insert 15 rows before the first one:

```
function MoveRowsDown() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.insertRowsBefore(1,15)
};
```

Change 15 with the number of rows you'd like to add

Comment: Thank you Martin for your response.  It's not actually doing what I'm intending and it's probabbly the way I'm explaining it.

Comment: Thank you Martin.  It's not actually doing what I  need, probably explanation.  Trying to get a running day to day of available teachers. Most current to past days maintaining history.  Example...                                                                             

Thursday, December 14, 2023  
TIME PERIOD Teacher
7:20 - 7:40 HR Smith
7:40 - 8:30 C Jones
  
Wednesday, December 13, 2023  
DAY 4 
TIME PERIOD Teacher
7:20 - 7:40 HR Diaz
7:40 - 8:30 C Monroe
  
Tuesday, December 12, 2023  
TIME PERIOD Teacher
7:20 - 7:40 HR Luther
7:40 - 8:30 C Smith

Comment: Thank you, Martin. It's not actually doing what I need, probably explanation. Trying to get a running day to day of available teachers. Most current to past days maintaining history. Example... 

/*Thursday, December 14, 2023 
7:20 - 7:40 HR Smith 
7:40 - 8:30 C Jones 

Wednesday, December 13, 2023
7:20 - 7:40 HR Diaz 
7:40 - 8:30 C Monroe 

Tuesday, December 12, 2023 
7:20 - 7:40 HR Luther
7:40 - 8:30 C Smith*/